# acts-as-taggable-on with simple text input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm a RoR newbie and i'm trying to create a simple blog platform. Currenty i'm stuck on making a tagging possibility.

I've installed [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem, added `acts_as_taggable` to my `post` model. Here is my form (based on [this](https://we.riseup.net/rails/tagging-tutorial) tutorial):

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tag_list %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :tags, :tag_list %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But when i'm trying to point by browser to i.e. `edit` form, all i get is the following error:

```
undefined method `merge' for :tag_list:Symbol
```

Have you any idea what am i doing wrong? It's probably something really simple :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need to change your tag input field to

```
<%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
```

The acts-as-taggable-on gem creates a model attribute called `tag_list` which you should be able to access like any other model attribute in a form.

Comment: when i'll make it this way, form is rendered well but on send, i'm getting `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: tag_list`.

Comment: You may need to add `:tag_list` to the `attr_accessible` call in your model then if you have that set up.

Comment: wow, strange thing, i've tried that earlier and it was not working, probably some typo, thanks for your help! :)